# Show that these rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the rings $2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic.
I find that if i make a map $\phi$:$2 \mathbb{Z}$ $\longmapsto$ $3\mathbb{Z}$ the map homomorphism works. so the only thing that i need is to show that $\phi$ is not surjective. How do i show that.

Comment: Again?! This was asked 2-3 days ago...and who knows how many times more in the past. Look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146568/how-are-2-mathbbz-ncong3-mathbbz-different-as-rings/1146646#1146646

Comment: @Timbuc: Then vote to close it as a duplicate. I don't think I've seen it.

Comment: I think, Timbuc is right. Moreover the web is full of solutions for this standard homework exercise, e.g., see [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m31x10/public_html/hw-solns.pdf), [here](http://math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/berkeley/math113/homework/hw6-solns.pdf), and [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~minnes/archive/spring2013/103B/files/103Bsp13_hw4_sol.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: how many elements $x$ are there such that for any $y$ we have $x\cdot y=y+y$?